# Escaping a parenthesis in grep/ack

Tags: regex, grep, ack

I want to look for the string "methodname(", but I am unable to escape the "(". How can I get

```
grep methodname( *
```

or

```
ack-grep methodname( *
```

to work?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's two things interpreting the `(`: the shell, and `ack-grep`.

You can use `''`, `""`, or `\` to escape the `(` from the shell, e.g.

```
grep 'methodname(' *
grep "methodname(" *
grep methodname\( *
```

`grep` uses a basic regular expression language by default, so `(` isn't special.  (It would be if you used `egrep` or `grep -E` or `grep -P`.)

On the other hand, `ack-grep` takes Perl regular expressions as input, in which `(` is also special, so you'll have to escape that too.

```
ack-grep 'methodname\(' *
ack-grep "methodname\\(" *
ack-grep methodname\\\( *
ack-grep 'methodname[(]' *
ack-grep "methodname[(]" *
ack-grep methodname\[\(\] *
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to do the escaping of the paren, for Perl, use the -Q flag.  `ack -Q 'methodname('`

Comment: Single quotes are best if you want to search for e.g. PHP variables prefixed with `$`. But then again, single quotes forces you to use ugly escaping if you want to search for strings containing single quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254509/how-to-escape-single-quotes-in-bash-grep

Comment: I never knew about ack-grep - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `\` before the `(`.

Small demo:

```
$ cat file
bar
methodname(
foo
$ grep -n methodname\( file
2:methodname(
$
```

Enclosing the pattern in single or double quotes also works:

```
$ grep -n 'methodname(' file
2:methodname(
$ grep -n "methodname(" file
2:methodname(
$
```

Comment: Works in grep but not ack. Ack thinks it's part of a group (I think)

Comment: The problem is that the paren has to be escaped for the shell, and also for ack.

Comment: `ack 'methodname\('` or `ack -Q 'methodname('`