# How can I escape single quotes in Bash/Grep?

Tags: linux, bash, escaping, grep

I want to search with grep for a string that looks like this:

```
something ~* 'bla'
```

I tried this, but the shell removes the single quotes. Argh...

```
grep -i '"something ~* '[:alnum:]'"' /var/log/syslog
```

What would be the correct search?

Comment: Shell removes single quotes inside double quotes? first time I see it! :)

Comment: He has single quotes inside double quotes inside single quotes: the regex begins with `'"` not just `"`

Comment: @Matteo, yes, hard to see at first sight :)

Comment: The canonical is probably *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)* (2009. 26 answers. 1380 votes). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings/16605140#16605140) for a relatively simple syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
grep -i "something ~\* '[[:alnum:]]*'" /var/log/syslog
```

works for me.

- escape the first `*` to match a literal `*` instead of making it the zero-or-more-matches character:
  `~*` would match zero or more occurrences of `~` while
  `~\*` matches the expression `~*` after `something`
- use double brackets around `:alnum:` (see example [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html))
- use a `*` after `[[:alnum::]]` to match not only **one** character between your single quotes but several of them
- the single quotes don't have to be escaped at all because they are contained in an expression that is limited by double quotes.

Answer (score 43):

If you *do* need to look for quotes in quotes in quotes, there are ugly constructs that will do it.

```
echo 'And I said, "he said WHAT?"'
```

works as expected, but for another level of nesting, the following **doesn't work** as expected:

```
echo 'She said, "And I said, \'he said WHAT?\'"'
```

Instead, you need to escape the inner single quotes *outside* the single-quoted string:

```
echo 'She said, "And I said, '\''he said WHAT?'\''"'
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
echo 'She said, "And I said, '"'"'he said WHAT?'"'"'"'
```

It ain't pretty, but it works.  :)

Of course, all this is moot if you put things in variables.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ i_said="he said WHAT?"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ she_said="And I said, '$i_said'"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf 'She said: "%s"\n' "$she_said"
She said: "And I said, 'he said WHAT?'"
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

:-)

Comment: Thanks for the brief overview, I just +1 to raise your score to 10k :)

Comment: What about `\n` is such case ? `sudo sh -c 'echo '\''A\nB'\'''`. Does `\n` need to be escaped out of the single quotes ?

Comment: @oldergod, `\n` is not support by many implementations of `echo`.  It's supported by the built-in `echo` that bash uses, but it doesn't work in Bourne compatibility mode (i.e. when bash is run as `/bin/sh`) and it's not there in the echo built in to FreeBSD's tcsh.  I recommend that you use `printf` if you want `\n` to work consistently.  As for your question ... my advice is that you experiment ... or more sage advice would be: **If the code is unclear, use different code.**

Comment: @ghoti: Good advice re inconsistencies of `echo` and using `printf` instead, but you have the behavior of `bash` backward: when running in POSIX compatibility mode (not "Bourne compatibility mode"), `"\n"` and other escape sequences _are_ recognized by the `echo` builtin (so as to conform with POSIX), whereas by default `echo` performs _no_ backslash interpretation, unless you use the (`bash`-specific) `-e` option (conversely, `-E` turns backlash-sequence interpretation explicitly off). In POSIX compatibility mode the echo `builtin` supports no options at all, and thus _invariably_ interprets.

Comment: @mklement0, re terminology, yes, I've updated my colloquialisms since I wrote that comment. :) Re escape sequences, I know you know how this works, so I think we must be miscommunicating. In POSIX mode, bash's builtin echo does not interpret escape sequences like `\n` as anything but the two characters `\ ` and `n`. Try: `bash --posix -c 'echo "one\ntwo"'`. I note also that the `/bin/echo` from coreutils behaves as I would expect. `dash`, on the other hand, which IIRC is the default `sh` on Ubuntu, DOES interpret escape sequences when launched as `sh`. Could it be that you tested with dash?

Comment: @ghoti: Oops! Thanks for that. I forgot that the makers of _OS X_ must have felt so strongly about POSIX compliance that they created `/bin/sh` as _a separate Bash binary_ in which option `xpg_echo` is implicitly ON, causing the interpretation of sequences such as `\n`. While using a mere _symlink_ named `sh` to `/bin/bash` puts Bash in POSIX compatibility mode, `xpg_echo` remains off. In other words: _what I described only applies to OS X_; on other platforms you'd have to run `shopt -s xpg_echo` to get that behavior. The BSD `/bin/echo` implementation does _not_ interpret escape sequences.

Comment: @ghoti: Yes, `dash` is being a good citizen here by interpreting `\n`, ..., as [POSIX mandates](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). It is curious that `bash` doesn't also behave that way by default when running in POSIX compatibility mode. You have to admire OS X's pluckiness in trying to fix that, but ultimately I think it was misguided.

Comment: @mklement0, Actually, the interpretation of those sequences is for [XSI conformance](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html), which is (mostly) inclusive of but not equivalent to POSIX.1. As the document you linked to states, ***"The following character sequences shall be recognized on XSI-conformant systems within any of the arguments:"*** I suppose it would be good to know whether "POSIX comatibility mode" refers to POSIX.1, POSIX:2001 (SUS), which I think would include XSI, or something else.

Comment: I appreciate your digging deeper, @ghoti; to complement what you found: specifically, XSI is an _optional superset_ of what's required for POSIX conformance (still applies as of the current POSIX standard, [POSIX.1-2008, 2013 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html)). `getconf _XOPEN_UNIX` tells whether a given system supports XSI, `getconf _XOPEN_VERSION` reports the XSI version. Both OSX 10.11, Linux 3.x-kernel systems report support. Linux is not officially certified, but OSX is (UNIX 03), which explains why they went out of their way to tweak Bash.

Comment: @ghoti: Final thoughts re `bash` behavior: You can get the `echo` behavior of an _XSI-conformant_ POSIX system by _manually_ turning on `shopt -s xpg_echo` (irrespective of POSIX compatibility mode; this is what OSX bakes into `/bin/sh`). By contrast, you cannot get the `echo` behavior of a _non-XSI_ POSIX system at all, because Bash supports `-e` and `-E` even in POSIX compatibility mode. As an aside: on an XSI-conformant system it is apparently OK for the _utility_ form of `echo` _not_ to support XSI features, as long as the _shell's builtin_ does - both OSX and Linux exhibit this.

Comment: Very interesting. For reference, FreeBSD's `/bin/sh`, which is based on the Almquist shell, *does* include `-e` option, and *does not* by default interpret any of the XSI sequences. The documentation states "*The current version of sh is close to the IEEE Std 1003.1 (POSIX.1) specification for the shell. It only supports features designated by POSIX, plus a few Berkeley extensions.*" It's amazing that we all get along as well as we do.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

- character classes are specified with `[[:alnum:]]` (two brackets)
- `[[:alnum:]]` is matching only **one** character. To match zero or more characters `[[:alnum:]]*`
- you can just use `" "` to quote the regex:

  ```
    grep -i "something ~\* '[[:alnum:]]*'" /var/log/syslog
  ```

Comment: @Matteo - sure it does, if it's intended to be taken literally.  `~*` means "*zero or more '~' characters*".

Comment: @Graham, thank for the correction. I missed that he was looking for a literal '*'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, as per your expression, that you are using first `'`, then `"`. If you want to escape the single quotes, you can either use `'` and escape them, or use double quotes. Also, as [Matteo comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254509/how-can-i-escape-single-quotes-in-bash-grep/7254543#7254543), character classes have double square brackets. Either:

```
grep -i "something \~\* '[[:alnum:]]+'" /var/log/syslog
```

or

```
grep -i 'something ~* \'[[:alnum:]]+\'' /var/log/syslog
```