# comparing 2 files with a searchable key

Tags: awk, gawk

Good day,

I have been trying to find a solution to a similar problem asked in [comparing 2 files using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592736/awk-compare-columns-from-two-files-impute-values-of-another-column) but I can't seem to get my head around it. Looking for some kind assistance.

I have 2 files that I would like to compare. Mock-up contents of file1 and file2 are shown below:

**file1:**

```
50       0004312805201        06740         2310821                                                                                                                                
50      0004986504201        00845         2310837                                                                                                                                
50      0003913155201        47679         2310762                                                                                                                                
50      0004997395201        2035          2311180                                                                                                                                
50      0001147242201        15000         23108723                                                                                                                                
50      0005771878201        13545         I3840000
```

**file2:**

```
0003913155 A

0005771878 A

0004312805 A

0000000015 B

0000000012 B

1111111111 E
```

I need to perform a `substring` on field2 from file1 to produce a `10 character length searchable key value` and find the matching value in field1 of file2.

If a match is found, print out the entire file1 row with field2 from file2 appended as a new field.

If no match, print out the entire file1 row with the string "NO" appended as a new field. Output would be best redirected to a file.

Example output is shown below.

**Output:**

```
50       0004312805201        06740         2310821 A                                                                                                                               
50      0004986504201        00845         2310837 NO                                                                                                                             
50      0003913155201        47679         2310762 A                                                                                                                               
50      0004997395201        2035          2311180 NO                                                                                                                             
50      0001147242201        15000         23108723 NO                                                                                                                               
50      0005771878201        13545         I3840000 A
```

How would you guys suggest I tackle this via `awk` or `GNU-awk`? Having issues in preparing the searchable key substring and using it in `awk/GNU-awk` to build the array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am spinning my wheels at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: *to produce a 10 character length searchable key* - could that key NOT start from the beginning of the field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using awk to match a column in log file and print the entire line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076186/using-awk-to-match-a-column-in-log-file-and-print-the-entire-line)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
     FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
     { s=substr($2,1,10); print $0,(s in a ?a[s]:"No") }
    ' file2 file1 > your_output_file
```

Input:

```
$ cat file1
50 0004312805201 06740 2310821
50 0004986504201 00845 2310837
50 0003913155201 47679 2310762
50 0004997395201 2035 2311180
50 0001147242201 15000 23108723
50 0005771878201 13545 I3840000 

$ cat file2
0003913155 A
0005771878 A
0004312805 A
0000000015 B
0000000012 B
1111111111 E
```

Output

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{s=substr($2,1,10);print $0, (s in a ? a[s] : "No") }' file2 file1
50 0004312805201 06740 2310821 A
50 0004986504201 00845 2310837 No
50 0003913155201 47679 2310762 A
50 0004997395201 2035 2311180 No
50 0001147242201 15000 23108723 No
50 0005771878201 13545 I3840000  A
```

Comment: I will review the feedback provided tomorrow and reply back with comments. Thanks to all that responded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what OP means with `produce a 10 character length searchable key value`. I interpret it as: *the value in field 1 of file2 must be a substring of field 2 in file1*.

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[0-9]/ && NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }   # read values from file2 in array
/^[0-9]/{
   f=0;
   for (i in a){                         # loop over field 1 of file2
      if (index($2, i)){                 # if i can be found in field 2 of file1
         print $0, a[i];                 # print $0 with $2 from file2
         f++;
         break;
      }
   }
}
/^[0-9]/ && !f{ print $0, "NO" }         # if no match, print "NO" line
```

With input of

```
$ cat file1
50 0004312805201 06740 2310821
50 0004986504201 00845 2310837
50 0003913155201 47679 2310762
50 0004997395201 2035 2311180
50 0001147242201 15000 23108723
50 0005771878201 13545 I3840000
```

and

```
$ cat file2
0003913155 A

0005771878 A

0004312805 A

0000000015 B

0000000012 B

1111111111 E
```

calling tst.awk will generate output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
50 0004312805201 06740 2310821 A
50 0004986504201 00845 2310837 NO
50 0003913155201 47679 2310762 A
50 0004997395201 2035 2311180 NO
50 0001147242201 15000 23108723 NO
50 0005771878201 13545 I3840000 A
```

Or, use a oneliner:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]/ && NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next } /^[0-9]/{f=0;for (i in a){if (index($2, i)){print $0, a[i];f++;break;}}}/^[0-9]/ && !f{ print $0, "NO" }' file2 file1
```