# how I search > into bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing some script to make a directory, but I want firstly sure that the name that the user insert is correct. for this issue I wrote something like below (FILE.txt is the file which the user name saved in)

```
if grep -q  '>' FILE.txt
  then
  echo "You should avoid inserting ">" in your code!"
  fi
```

But it seems that the bash thought that I want to insert to output and so it give this error:
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
Do anybody have some idea? tnx for help

Comment: I've always liked referring folks to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9712555/1072112) when there's a problem with quoting.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with your `grep` line, it's with your `echo` line. Your shell sees it as:

```
echo "You should avoid inserting "  >  " in your code!"
```

You can fix this simply by removing the quotes in the middle of the sentence, or using single quotes like:

```
echo "You should avoid inserting '>' in your code!"
```

Comment: I think that OP wants to save `""` around `>` like this: `echo You should avoid inserting '">"' in your code!`

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the quote in your echo statement:

```
if grep -q '>' file.txt; then
    echo "You should avoid inserting \">\" in your code!"
else
    echo "code is good"
fi
```