# Saving arguments passed from xargs to bash as a variable for processing

Tags: bash, xargs

I am trying to run many commands in parallel, and need to do some string manipulation on the input first. How can I make the below example work?

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs -n 1 -P 20 -i sh -c "v={}; echo $v"
```

When I use this, `$v` is null. Why is it not being saved as the value of `{}`?

Comment: Your `$v` is null because it's being expanded by the command line rather than by xargs's call to `sh`.  Use single quotes to keep the dollar sign from being interpreted by the wrong shell. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9712555/1072112) for some insight on how different quotes work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parent shell is expanding `$v` *before* the string gets passed to `xargs`.

Suppose your `find` command finds a subdirectory named `./stuff`.

First, the parent `bash` shell (the one you typed the `find` command into) will expand `$v`, because the string is in double quotes. You currently have no value set for variable `v`, so it expands to an empty string.

Next, the arguments get passed to `xargs`, which will see this: `v={}; echo`

Then, `xargs` will read `./stuff` from the pipe, and replace `{}` with `./stuff`

Finally, the `sh` command is executed by `xargs`, and `sh` will see this: `v=./stuff; echo`

To fix this, you need to either escape the `$` so that the parent shell doesn't expand it, or use single quotes to avoid variable expansion. You should also probably quote the strings so that any directory names with spaces in them don't cause problems with the final `sh` command:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs -n 1 -P 20 -i sh -c "v=\"{}\"; echo \"\$v\""
```

OR

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs -n 1 -P 20 -i sh -c 'v="{}"; echo "$v"'
```

With either command, the final `sh` process will see: `v="./stuff"; echo "$v"`

By the way, one way to see for yourself that this is indeed what is happening would be to set a value for `v` in the parent shell, then run your original command. The shell will expand `$v` to whatever value you set, and you will see that value repeated for every directory found by `find`.

```
$ v=foobar
$ find . -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs -n 1 -P 20 -i sh -c "v={}; echo $v"
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
...
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you would do:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | parallel -P 20 'v={}; echo "$v"'
```