# Pass sed via ssh command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sed

I try to pass sed via ssh command as [1] to ssh command, but it does not work.
I do ssh to a host, like 'ssh ld3646'. In my console, I input

```
ssh ld3646 'sed -i 's/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="4"/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="64"/g' /etc/sysconfig/nfs'
```

file /etc/sysconfig/nfs is not changed at all. It works when I do 'ssh ld3646' and type

```
sed -i 's/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="4"/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="64"/g' /etc/sysconfig/nfs'
```

Can someone help on why doesn't it work?

Comment: Check this out: http://gt-dev.blogspot.com/2015/05/bash-ssh-how-to-invoke-command-remotely.html

Answer (score 0):

Notice how you have two sets of single quotes? That doesn't work. Single quotes don't nest. Luckily, the outer set of quotes isn't necessary.

```
ssh ld3646 sed -i 's/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="4"/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="64"/g' /etc/sysconfig/nfs
```

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing quote confusion.

The quote immediately before the sed script EXITS the quoted string that begins with `sed`.

I provided some strategies for handling nested quotes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9712555/1072112), which might be enlightening.  In your case, an easy strategy might be simply to change quotes:

```
ssh ld3646 "sed -i 's/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER=\"4\"/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER=\"64\"/g' /etc/sysconfig/nfs"
```

Note that the embedded double quotes are escaped, to avoid precisely this problem.

Another option for visual simplification might be to use variables:

```
sedscript='s/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="4"/USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="64"/g'
ssh ld3646 "sed -i '$sedscript'"
```

This last one works because single quotes that are embedded in double-quoted strings do not block variable expansion.