# Alias in bash to add formatted current date to git commit message

Tags: bash, date, alias

I am trying to add alias for a default commit message, something like this:

```
alias gc='git commit -m "Default commit: $(date)"'
```

but I don't like date's default format and would like to change it to this:

```
date +'%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S' # Tuesday, 02 May 2017 23:12:07
```

I run into problem of how to build this in alias. I cannot handle the multiple double and single quotes. Can someone help?

---

Edit.

Thanks for the suggestion on using function and the code. Based on that I have made this, slightly changed:

```
gc () 
{ 
    if [ "$#" == "0" ]; then
        itsmsg="Deafult commit";
    else
        itsmsg="$*";
    fi;
    git commit -m "$itsmsg ($(date +'%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S'))"
}
```

Comment: Use a function instead.

Comment: Sort of duplicate-ish: [How to escape single quotes in Bash/Grep](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7254509/1072112)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ANSI C quoting so that you can escape single quotes inside single quotes:

```
alias gc=$'git commit -m "Default commit: $(date +\'%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S\')"'
```

Comment: With three forms of quotes in use, you'd be in trouble if you wanted one more level of nesting. How do you nest single quotes inside single quotes? `echo 'You can'\''t.'`

Answer (score 4):

As @123 mentioned, you should use a function instead of an alias. This eliminates a level of quoting.

```
gc () {
  git commit -m "Default commit: $(date +'%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S')" "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed one of other solutions. But i don't know where to define functions and how to use them in shell. Besides, the gc purpose is to quickly commit. If i needed custom message, i would type full command. I'll fiddle with function and see how it goes.

Comment: You define the function in the same place you currently define your alias, and you use it just like any other command.

Comment: To be clear, we're talking about shell aliases here, not git aliases as would be defined in the `[alias]` section of your `~/.gitconfig` file.

Comment: What should this look like in a .gitconfig. This won't work to just add to the config. Thanks in advance!