# `error: unbalanced parenthesis` while checking if an item presents in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":["one","two","three"],"B":["fopur","give","six"]})
```

when I do,

```
df.B.str.contains("six").any()
out[2]=True
```

when I do,

```
df.B.str.contains("six)").any()
```

I am getting the below error,

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
    868     if source.next is not None:
    869         assert source.next == ")"
--> 870         raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
    871 
    872     if flags & SRE_FLAG_DEBUG:

error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 3
```

Please help!

Comment: That does not look like a full stack trace.

Comment: you want full trace ?

Comment: You should get in the habit of posting that, yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set `regex=False` in `in pandas.Series.str.contains`:

```
df.B.str.contains("six)", regex=False).any()
```

If you want to match irrespective of case,

```
df.B.str.contains("Six)", case=False, regex=False).any() 
out[]: True
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Info:

Parenthesis are special characters in regular expressions that need to be "escaped",  see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761242/escaping-a-parenthesis-in-grep-ack) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html).

Comment: Probably the simpler method.

Answer (score 8):

You need escape `)` by `\` because special regex character:

```
df.B.str.contains("six\)").any()
```

More general:

```
import re

df.B.str.contains(re.escape("six)")).any()
```

Comment: actually I am passing a list one by one to check if it is exists, so I cannot hardcode this escape like this, my actual code is like,

`for item in mylist:
    if df.B.str.contains(item):
         print(item)`

Comment: @pyd. How does that prevent you from properly escaping the strings?

Comment: Yes, it is difference. Joe solution dont escape and by default all regex are not compiled (I hope it is good wording). So if use some regex, my solution working and Joe solution not.

Comment: But if dont want use regex, then need Joe solution, if need regex (e.g. | for join strings) need my solution.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael

Comment: Need `df.B.str.contains("Six", case= False).any()`, untested, because on phone only.